# The has_many_polymorphs plugin is giving me this error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, plugins, has-many-polymorphs

This is the error in my logs when I try to create a new model:

```
/rubyprograms/dreamstill/vendor/plugins/has_many_polymorphs/lib/has_many_polymorphs/configuration.rb:7: Configuration is not a class (TypeError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /rubyprograms/dreamstill/vendor/plugins/has_many_polymorphs/lib/has_many_polymorphs.rb:23
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /rubyprograms/dreamstill/vendor/plugins/has_many_polymorphs/init.rb:2
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/plugin.rb:81
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `run_initializers'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
    from /rubyprograms/dreamstill/config/environment.rb:5
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6
```

It's from the has_many_polymorphs plugin...

here is config/environment.rb:

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
Dreamstill::Application.initialize!
```

This is `/rubyprograms/dreamstill/vendor/plugins/has_many_polymorphs/lib/has_many_polymorphs/configuration.rb`:

```
module Rails #:nodoc:
  class Configuration

    def has_many_polymorphs_options
      ::HasManyPolymorphs.options
    end

    def has_many_polymorphs_options=(hash)
      ::HasManyPolymorphs.options = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(hash)
    end

  end  
end
```

Comment: As always you didn't show any code so we should imaginate what causes an error :D. Show your `config/environment.rb` code :)

Comment: nothing interesting :). So an issue is inside your plugin in this file and line 23: `/rubyprograms/dreamstill/vendor/plugins/has_many_polymorphs/lib/has_many_polymorphs.rb:23`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The quick answer:**

Your `has_many_polymorphs` plugin is broken. And I think you've included it in your `environment.rb` file on LINE 5

**UPD**

as you can see `/rubyprograms/dreamstill/vendor/plugins/has_many_polymorphs/lib/has_many_polymorphs.rb:23` there is an error in `has_many_polymorphs.rb` file n line 23. Fix it :D. Or don't use broken plugins.

```
rails plugin remove has_many_polymorphs
```

Comment: i need to use this plugin... how can I fix it? do you need to see `/rubyprograms/dreamstill/vendor/plugins/has_many_polymorphs/lib/has_many_polymorphs.rb:23` or `rubyprograms/dreamstill/vendor/plugins/has_many_polymorphs/lib/has_many_polymorphs/configuration.rb:7`

Comment: Look into source code, find an error and try to figure out why is it broken. I don't know what this gem about. You can send bugreport to plugin author and ask him to fix it as well.

Comment: You can show it but I am pretty sure that there is something coplex and it won't be enough to see those lines.

Comment: ok I posted one of the files... the error is pointing to the fact that Configuration shouldn't be a class...

Comment: where did you get this plugin? This is some old piece of code that won't work with Rails 3. Remove it from your project. Write your own one. Never use too many plugins. And never use out of date plugins.